# Armadillo compiler error

Tags: armadillo

I am using armadillo C++ library. I see below  error when doing the compile. Does it require new version of GCC compiler I am having "gcc version 4.1.2" right now with my system

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/armadillo.dir/src/wrapper.cpp.o
In file included from /home/mukuar01/armadillo/armadillo-7.800.3/src/wrapper.cpp:29:
/home/mukuar01/armadillo/armadillo-7.800.3/tmp/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:168:6: error: #error "*** Need a newer compiler ***"
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/armadillo.dir/src/wrapper.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/armadillo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need a newer version of gcc. At least version 4.4.0 is required. You can check in the [source code](https://github.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/blob/0d842cd87f9c101ead5a5f07275938a88f84e5d6/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp), line 167. Versions 4.7.0 and 4.7.1 are also not supported due to a [bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53549).

You could try to use clang instead of gcc, but not sure which version is needed.
Or you could try with older versions of armadillo, but I am not sure how far you'd need to go back.